# Svelte - pass use:action to component child

Tags: svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm new to Svelte and it is very likely I'm missing something here.

I'm using [sveltestrap](https://github.com/bestguy/sveltestrap) and [svelte-spa-router](https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router).
When I try creating a `<Button>` (from sveltestrap) and using the `link` action (from svelte-spa-router) like this:

```html
<script>
  import { Button } from 'sveltestrap';
  import {link} from 'svelte-spa-router';
  let myLink = '/foo/bar';
 </script>
<Button use:link={myLink}>
  Click here
</Button>
```

I get the following error:

```
[!] (plugin svelte) ValidationError: Actions can only be applied to DOM elements, not components
```

My expectation was that somehow (??) the `<Button>` would 'pass down' the `use:link` to the child html node.

Is there a best practice for this type of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a button component, you might want to change your code to use `push` rather than `link` in the `on:click` event.

```html
<script>
  import { Button } from 'sveltestrap';
  import { push } from 'svelte-spa-router';
  let myLink = '/foo/bar';
</script>

<Button on:click={() => push(myLink)}>
  Click here
</Button>
```