# Svelte: How to pass action to component?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

There is a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65649357/svelte-pass-useaction-to-component-child) but I do not believe the answer applies to my use case.

I'm using [Svelte MaterialUI](https://sveltematerialui.com/) and attempting to extend the [DataTable](https://sveltematerialui.com/demo/data-table) component with the ability to drag and drop rows.  I'm using the [svelte-dnd-action](https://github.com/isaacHagoel/svelte-dnd-action) module to support the drag and drop behaviors.

The following works just fine.  I'm able to drag and drop rows of the table.

```html
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody use:dndzone{...opts}>
     ...data
  <tbody>
</table>
```

However, when attempting to plug the module into a Material UI Component, I receive an error stating "actions can only be applied to DOM elements, not components."

```html
<DataTable>
  <Head>...</Head>
  <Body use:dndzone={...opts}>
    ...Data
  </Body>
</DataTable>
```

The definition of the `Body` component looks like this:

```html
<tbody
  use:useActions={use}
  use:forwardEvents
  class="mdc-data-table__content {className}"
  {...exclude($$props, ['use', 'class'])}
><slot></slot></tbody>

<script>
  import {setContext} from 'svelte';
  import {get_current_component} from 'svelte/internal';
  import {forwardEventsBuilder} from '@smui/common/forwardEvents.js';
  import {exclude} from '@smui/common/exclude.js';
  import {useActions} from '@smui/common/useActions.js';
  const forwardEvents = forwardEventsBuilder(get_current_component());
  export let use = [];
  let className = '';
  export {className as class};
  setContext('SMUI:data-table:row:header', false);
</script>
```

Is there a way to forward my `Action` to this component? Or a better way to handle this use case?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general answer is that you cannot pass actions to a component.
That is, unless the component has this exposed for you.

Luckily the library you mention has it, as is written in their documentation:

> You can add actions to the components with use={[Action1, [Action2, action2Props], Action3]}.

So in your case the code I believe would be

```html
<Body use={[[dndzone, opts]]}>
```

Comment: FYI, the tag could look like this: `<Body use={[[dndzone, {items}]]} on:consider={handleConsider} on:finalize={handleFinalize} >`

Answer (score 8):

Action can only be applied to DOM element. However, it's possible to pass a function by property to a component, and this component can use this property in a "use" directive.

An example:

```html
<script>
  function myAction() {
    ...
  }
</script>

<!-- pass myAction in a property 'action' -->
<MyComponent action={myAction}/>
```

```html
<!-- MyComponent.svelte -->
<script>
  export let action;
</script>

<div use:action/>
```

If you look at the smui library, you'll see that every component export an 'use' property, and apply the content of this property to a dom element. `use:useActions={use}` inject the action defined in the `use` property as actions.

In other words, in smui, you can pass actions to components by using the `use` property.

```html
<Body use={myAction}/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm curious, would it be possible that `MyComponent.svelte` accepts an action if passed any, and not, if not. In my case, when I don't pass an action it throws an error