# Passing action to a component optionally

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I've learnt that it's possible to pass action to a component: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66142037/15943057. Now I wonder if it would be possible to pass one optionally.

I'm building a reusable `<Wrapper>` component that I want to be used with or without the action passed. If I try the answer linked above, but don't add `action={myAction}` (because I don't want any), I get two errors: (1) [HMR][Svelte] – "Unrecoverable error in : next update will trigger a full reload", (2) Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ctx[2].call'). To note, when I do add `action={myAction}`, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set a default that does nothing:

```html
<script>
  export let action = () => {};
  export let actionParams = undefined;
</script>

<div use:action={actionParams} >
    <slot/>
</div>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/144b7b96e6a74d19bb6a339e987d44be?version=3.48.0)