# Svelte: How to pass multiple actions to a component?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I've learnt that it's possible to pass an action to a component: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66142037/15943057. I wonder if it would be possible to pass multiple (any number of) actions to a single component?

Edit: I've tried to write an action that would apply actions passed as an argument, and it didn't work. But I just saw [this](https://github.com/sveltejs/rfcs/pull/60#issuecomment-938671917) comment, so I suppose it is possible. Perhaps my mistake was that I tried to add an attribute the `node.setAttribute(...)` way, maybe it could be done the Svelte way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the actions into one single action, e.g.

```html
<script>
    export let actions;
    
    const combinedActions = node => {
        const destructors = actions.map(
            ({ action, params }) => action(node, params)
        );
        
        return {
            destroy() {
                destructors.forEach(destructor => {
                    if (typeof destructor?.destroy == 'function')
                        destructor.destroy();
                })
            }
        };
    }
</script>

<div use:combinedActions >
    Child component
</div>
```

Usage example:

```html
<script>
    import Child from './Child.svelte';
    
    const color = (node, params) => node.style.color = params;
    const bg = node => {
        node.style.background = 'grey';
        
        return { destroy() { console.log('destroyed') } };
    }
    
    let checked = true;
</script>

<label>
    <input bind:checked type=checkbox />
    mounted
</label>

{#if checked}
    <Child actions={[
                 { action: color, params: 'red' },
                 { action: bg }
            ]} />
{/if}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fb168f62ee9443339d627d6726672216?version=3.48.0)

Comment: Is there a reason that `$: combinedActions` is reactive?

Comment: @Corrl I suppose it could be dropped. Just tested whether actions can change after having been applied; apparently they cannot.